# How can I compute the endomorphism ring $\text{End}_{R}(M)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $M = {\mathbb{C}}^2$ be the module over the polynomial algebra ${\mathbb{C}}[x]$ with $f(x)m = f(A)m$ action, where 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1&2\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$
How can I compute the endomorphism ring $\text{End}_{R}(M)$?

Comment: See which matrices commute with $A$?

Comment: Did you mean that you want $R=\mathbb C[x]$? (I'm guessing so, just making sure.)

Comment: @rschwieb yes. This is what I mean!

Answer (score 1):

An endomorphism of $M$ is first of all a linear transformation over $\mathbb C$, so it is given by a 2 by 2 matrix $B$. In other words $End_R(M) \subseteq End_{\mathbb C}(M) = M_2(\mathbb C)$.

In order for $B$ to be $R$-linear one needs to know that $B\,(x.v) = x.(B\,v)$ for every $v \in M$.

Now what?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I still do not understand how to prove this rigorously.

Comment: Which part are you unsure of how to prove rigorously? That an endomorphism of $M$ is also a linear transformation over $\mathbb C$? That matrices are equivalent to linear transformations once you choose a basis? That $f$ being an $R$-homomorphism is the same as a linear transformation for which $f(x.v) = x.f(v)$ for all $v$?

Comment: My issue is how to apply the last part in my problem. Also, why do you use an extra matrix $B$?

Comment: I just introduced $B$ to represent an element $B \in M_2(\mathbb C)$. The variable $B$ isn't really needed, but the condition that $B$ be $R$-linear will translate to equations for the entries of $B$.

Comment: ok. I am starting to understand. Thanks!

Comment: @Nicole Nice, I suggest adding/accepting your own answer to this question once you finish it.

Comment: Unfortunately I still haven't solved it.

Comment: If you like, you should post your work thus far, so if you are stuck we may give a hint.